# Export custom color scheme from PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have a simple question: how to export a custom made color scheme made in PhpStorm ?

I have created my own style in "Colors & Fonts", I gave him a name, he is a pretty beautiful child of mine... Except I can't export him to my other environments.

I try classical export: the .jar during the export does only contain the themes I've imported before in PhpStorm -- no `myTheme.icls` in there. Same thing for the `%APPDATA%` color folder, no theme here.

Furthermore, my theme is the only one I can delete in the editor.

Does someone can save my day?

Comment: All the custom themes should be present in the [CONFIG](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)`/colors`. Double check you are looking inside the correct location.

Comment: I have more than one time, and even now, no trace of my custom template in here. But i still have all the downloaded one.

Comment: No ideas then. You can try use some tool like Process Monitor on Windows to trace where this `.icls` file is loaded from.

Comment: do you use settingsRepository plugin? Try searching for your schema in `.PhpStorm<your version>/settingsRepository/repository/colors` or similar